# Assigning X in Systemverilog Enumerations

Tags: enums, system-verilog

Can we assign “x” to enumeration members? If yes, what is the 
advantage and if no, what is the limitation? Appreciate your help with this.

Comment: yes, you can, but how are you going to use it?

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to build a state machine and it was coming out uninitialized.

Comment: usually for the state machines you need to provide a reset function which would bring it into an initial state. there is no need the enum with 'x' in it. Besides, if you use it in a conditional statement, it will not work for indication the initial state. It will do something else or will be non-synthesizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign X to an enum if its base type is `logic`

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {U='x,A=0,B,C,D} e_type;
```

The is useful when you have a register with this enum data type and you need the X state to indicate uninitialized or an error condition.